# How to target a specific column in a specific row in Pyspark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to pass ' vin equal to the 1 idx' to update the value of the column

```py
+----------+---------+---+
|       vin|    vinar|idx|
+----------+---------+---+
|  wdwer43w| eqr21144|  1|
|Ebntyure43|Evirter45|  2|
+----------+---------+---+
cur='06City'

df4=df4.withColumn('vin',F.when(F.col('vin')==F.col('idx[1]'),cur).otherwise(F.col('vin')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition should be the index equals 1, not vin:

```
df4 = df4.withColumn('vin', F.when(F.col('idx') == 1, cur).otherwise(F.col('vin')))
```